# una mano soy nuevo en python

Tags: python-3.x

tengo dicho problema me arroja error

> "Error: (<class 'UnboundLocalError'>, UnboundLocalError("local variable 'objecto_encontrado' referenced before assignment"), <traceback object at 0x0000014686283A00>)"

este es mi codigo

```
time.sleep(1)
        if self.d.xpath('//androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[2]').exists:
            self.d.xpath('//androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[2]').click()
        self.d.xpath('//*[@text="CONTINUE"]').click()

    else:
        objecto_encontrado = UiWait.for_any([self.d])

    if(objecto_encontrado == self.d):
            return True 
    time.sleep(1)
    perfil_ingresado = self.d(className="android.widget.FrameLayout")
    while perfil_ingresado.exists:
        if not perfil_ingresado.exists:
            break
    
    perfil_ingresado = [
        self.d(text="OK"),
        self.d(clickable="true"),
        self.d(text="NOT NOW"),
        self.d(text="CONTINUE"),
        self.d(description="CONTINUE"),
        self.d(description="NOT NOW"),
        self.d(clickable="true")
    ]

    busqueda = []
    for element in perfil_ingresado:
        busqueda.append(element)  

    time.sleep(1)
    objectoEncontrado = UiWait.for_any(busqueda, 10)
    if objectoEncontrado:
        if objectoEncontrado in perfil_ingresado:
            if self.d(text="OK").exists():
                self.d(clickable="true").click(),
                self.d(description="NOT NOW").click(),
                self.d(description="CONTINUE").click(),
                self.d(clickable="NOT NOW").click(),
                self.d(text="CONTINUE").click()
                
        if objectoEncontrado in perfil_ingresado:
            return enums.MessengerStatus1.SUCCEL
    else:
        print("Buscando petisiones")
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ya hicistes esta misma pregunta y se te dio la respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/526361/c%c3%b3mo-corregir-el-error-local-variable-xyz-referenced-before-assignment

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque repite la misma pregunta, la cual ya tiene respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/526361/c%c3%b3mo-corregir-el-error-local-variable-xyz-referenced-before-assignment