# Cómo corregir el error "local > variable 'xyz' referenced before assignment"?

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo dicho problema me arroja error:

> "Error: (<class 'UnboundLocalError'>, UnboundLocalError("local
> variable 'objecto_encontrado' referenced before assignment"),
> <traceback object at 0x0000014686283A00>)"

Este es mi código:

```
time.sleep(1)
        if self.d.xpath('//androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[2]').exists:
            self.d.xpath('//androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[2]').click()
            self.d.xpath('//*[@text="CONTINUE"]').click()

        else:
            objecto_encontrado = UiWait.for_any([self.d])

        if(objecto_encontrado == self.d):
                return True 
        time.sleep(1)
        perfil_ingresado = self.d(className="android.widget.FrameLayout")
        while perfil_ingresado.exists:
            if not perfil_ingresado.exists:
                break
        
        perfil_ingresado = [
            self.d(text="OK"),
            self.d(clickable="true"),
            self.d(text="NOT NOW"),
            self.d(text="CONTINUE"),
            self.d(description="CONTINUE"),
            self.d(description="NOT NOW"),
            self.d(clickable="true")
        ]

        busqueda = []
        for element in perfil_ingresado:
            busqueda.append(element)  

        time.sleep(1)
        objectoEncontrado = UiWait.for_any(busqueda, 10)
        if objectoEncontrado:
            if objectoEncontrado in perfil_ingresado:
                if self.d(text="OK").exists():
                    self.d(clickable="true").click(),
                    self.d(description="NOT NOW").click(),
                    self.d(description="CONTINUE").click(),
                    self.d(clickable="NOT NOW").click(),
                    self.d(text="CONTINUE").click()
                    
            if objectoEncontrado in perfil_ingresado:
                return enums.MessengerStatus1.SUCCEL
        else:
            print("Buscando petisiones")
```

---

Candid Moe

aqui este es el codigo la parte que no me esta funcionando es a la hora de buscar en la lista

```
    time.sleep(1)
    objectoEncontrado = None
    if self.d.xpath('//androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[2]').exists:
        self.d.xpath('//androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[2]').click()
        self.d.xpath('//*[@text="CONTINUE"]').click()

        #objectoEncontrado = UiWait.for_any([self.d])

        if(objectoEncontrado == self.d):
            return True 
    
    perfil_ingresado = [
        self.d(text="OK"),
        self.d(clickable="true"),
        self.d(text="NOT NOW"),
        self.d(description="CONTINUE")
    ]

    busqueda = []
    for element in perfil_ingresado:
        busqueda.append(element)  

    objectoEncontrado = UiWait.for_any(busqueda, 10)
    if objectoEncontrado:
        if objectoEncontrado in perfil_ingresado:
            if self.d(text="OK").click():
                self.d(text="OK").click(),
                self.d(clickable="OK").click(),
                self.d(description="OK").click()
                
        if objectoEncontrado in perfil_ingresado:
            return enums.MessengerStatus1.SUCCEL
```

Comment: Buen día, el código no tenía formato correcto, lo cambié para que se viera correctamente en tu pregunta pero la indentación está mal, ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y corregir la indentación?

Comment: Por cierto, el error te aparece porque estás utilizando la variable `objecto_encontrado` en tu `if` pero no ha sido inicializada antes, la única asignación que se hace es a través del `else` anterior pero si esa condición no se cumple entonces la variable no está definida.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: SO no funciona como un foro. Por ejemplo, añadiste info en un campo titulado Tu Respuesta. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). :) (**y borra la no respuesta de abajo!**)

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes un `if`:

```
    if self.d.xpath('//androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[2]').exists:
        self.d.xpath('//androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[2]').click()
        self.d.xpath('//*[@text="CONTINUE"]').click()
    else:
        objecto_encontrado = UiWait.for_any([self.d])
```

Si la condición es `False`, asignas un valor a `objecto_encontrado`. Si es `True`, no le asignas nada, por lo que queda *unbound*, o sea "indefinido", "inexistente".

En la siguiente instrucción, preguntas por el valor de esa variable. Si la condición previa fue `True`, entonces `objecto_encontrado` no existe, y se produce el error

```
    if(objecto_encontrado == self.d):
            return True
```

Solución: Inicializa `objecto_encontrado` al empezar con algún valor apropiado. Típicamente le asignas `None`

```
    objecto_encontrado = None
    if self.d.xpath('//androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[2]').exists:
        self.d.xpath('//androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[2]').click()
        self.d.xpath('//*[@text="CONTINUE"]').click()

    else:
        objecto_encontrado = UiWait.for_any([self.d])

    if(objecto_encontrado == self.d):
            return True
```

Comment: eh echo lo que me comentaron pero aun no me soluciona no da el error pero las funciones en la lista no me funcionan

Comment: Tienes varios errores entonces. Como no publicas un código completo, que pueda copiar y probar, no es posible ayudarte.

Comment: sera que me puedes escribir por discord geraldking#9514

Comment: Sólo contesto preguntas en StackOverflow. El chat es improductivo, ineficiente y una pésima alternativa de trabajo. Prepara bien tu pregunta y te ayudare. El chat es para los flojos.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/526463/279335